# Multiple Custom Field Query

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have a unique situation where I need to filter on 2 custom fields where 1st field is expiry and values of "" and greater than todays date are valid and 2 field is a number which should be greater than some value. So Ideally I need to put a OR relation for 2 possibilities of 1st field with and between 1st field and second field.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

that should be fairly simple using [Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) parameter of the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object

you can set the relation and set as many fields as you like:

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR', //realation 
        array(
            'key' => 'color', //first custom field
            'value' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price', //second custom field
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I know about this but the problem is little more complex here.
    $args['meta_query'] = array( 
        'relation' => 'OR',
                  array(
                    'key' => 'expiry',
                    'value' => $now ,
                    'compare' => '>='
                  ),
                  array(
                    'key' => 'expiry',
                    'value' => '' ,
                    'compare' => '=='
                            ),
      );

and I want to check these 2 inaddition to
       array ( 'key' => 'views', 'value' => '40', 'compare' => '>=')